# How to reduce the code for this function

Tags: php, reduce

Input array `$items`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
        )
)
```

---

Result of `print_r(foo($items))`

```
Array
(
    [2] => 1
    [5] => 1
)
```

---

Function `foo()`

```
function foo($items)
{
    $result = array();
    foreach($items => $array)
    {
        $result[$array['id']] = TRUE;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

How can I simply write this array transformation with standards PHP functions, like `array_flip()` or something else. Is it possible?

Comment: Maybe you want to take a look at underscore.js's php brotha, http://brianhaveri.github.com/Underscore.php/, especially the `pluck` func: `array_fill_keys( __::pluck($items, 'id'), true )`

Comment: @biziclop, thx but I want to use only standart PHP functions

Comment: So basically, you want to simplify code that's simplified to the max by introducing PHP functions which internally will do the same thing?

Comment: Why do you need this? An array with ID as key seems only useful, if it contains some useful values, but not a (always the same) constant.

Comment: @KingCrunch, I often use this feature for `<select>`s, one array I pass through "while", in which I check, if current value `isset` in array with indexes, like output in this question. Sorry, for my English.

Comment: If you treat the array as set (means: The ids as value) you can use `in_array()`, or even `array_diff()` (without `while(){}` of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a built in PHP function would only introduce the unnecessary overhead of additional function calls. What you have written is already an efficient method for creating the desired output from the given input.

I would recommend using your custom function if possible.

Comment: @Khior You know: Functions calls are fast and the builtin functions are all implemented in C. Do you _really_ think you will ever be able to _measure_ any difference? ;) ("Micro optimization is the root of all evil", especially when the optimized solution isn't even better)

Comment: @KingCrunch This is true - the overhead would be minimal. However, I would see any attempt to compress what is already an efficient method into yet fewer lines of code as just another form of Micro Optimization! ;) Also, you have to agree, his custom function is more readable than an approach using in-built functions, and the readability of one's code is key..

Answer (score 0):

```
$r = array_combine( 
  array_map(function($i){ return $i['id']; }, $items), // <-- key
  array_fill(0, count($items), true /* or 1 */)        // <-- value
);
```